# How can I return a single value integer from Linq from an array of objects that have other nested values

Tags: c#, linq, c#-6.0

I am trying to do a Linq query on a collection of dynamic objects based on the value of a sub-sub field, and then return the single value of a different field as an integer.

What I have so far is :

```
int itemId = (
                from x in ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)allpets.pets.collected)
                where x.stats.speciesId == 294
                select x.itemId
             ).SingleOrDefault()
```

The problem is, sometimes the result found has no field `x.itemId` which ends up causing an exception.

> 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' does not contain a definition for 'itemId'

I have tried  `x?.itemId` ,  `x.?itemId` , `x.itemId?`  , and `?x.itemId` which seem to be the only places I can capture for nulls.

The other part, is this is part of a more complex nested linq select, and where the value `294` is located, is actually `p.stats.speciesId` (snippet below so you can see why this needs to be inline)

```
List<MasheryTypes.pet> pets = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)json.pets).Select(
    p => new MasheryTypes.pet(
        Convert.ToBoolean(p.canBattle),
        p.creatureId,
        p.name,
        p.family,
        p.icon,
        p.qualityId,
        new MasheryTypes.petstats(
            p.stats.speciesId,
            p.stats.breedId,
            p.stats.petQualityId,
            p.stats.level,
            p.stats.health,
            p.stats.power,
            p.stats.speed
        ),
        p.strongAgainst?[0],
        p.typeId,
        p.weakAgainst?[0],
        cageable.Any(
            c => c == p.creatureId
        ),
        p.itemId = (from x in ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)allpets.pets.collected)
                    where x.stats.speciesId == p.stats.speciesId
                    select x.itemId).SingleOrDefault()
    )
).ToList();
```

Comment: Your pet-class seems not to have an `itemId`. Hard to tell without seeing the full class and its properties

Comment: @lokusking - it actually does, but is absent on records that do not require it.  the source of the data is not in my control.  I put a sample of the data here : https://paste.ee/p/VU25M   (was too large for pastebin)

Comment: Instead of using `dynamic`, I would create static classes based on the json  format and deserialize to that. Try Visual Studio's "Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes" feature.

Comment: @JasonP - thank you, but that is a solution for an issue I did not address on this question.  The question is for returning an integer from a value in an object based on the query result of a different nested value in the object. Whether I use dynamic or static is irrelevant, and for information, this is converting into a static object.  Dynamic for the purpose of reading unknowns since the structure is not identical for each sub-object within a class is logical.  Please review the paste, and you will see that the data is only mostly consistent, hence why some pets don't have an itemid field.

Comment: `select x?.itemId ?? 0` works for me

Comment: @IvanStoev - thank you.  That resolved my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
int itemId = (
            from x in ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)allpets.pets.collected)
            where x.GetType().GetProperty("itemId") != null && x.stats.speciesId == 294
            select x.itemId
         ).SingleOrDefault()
```